# Issue with pyttsx3

Tags: python, typeerror, voice, pyttsx

I am trying to set up a condition so that I can switch between voices for my AI however I am running into the error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

This is my code for this section:

```
def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def getvoices(voice):
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    if voice == 1:
        engine.setProperty('voice', voice[0].id)
        speak ("Jarvis at your service")
    if voice == 2:
        engine.setProperty('voice', voice[1].id)
        speak ("Friday at your service")
```

Is anyone able to help? Being coded on python 3.9

Comment: I'am not familiar with pyttsx3, but if `voice == 1`, then you cannot do the getitem access `voice[0]`. Maybe it should be `voices[0].id`?

Comment: Ah thank you! that fixed it! you look at an issue so long you cant see it